# Can we use a lambda-expression as the default value for a function argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Refering to the C++11 specification (5.1.2.13):

> A *lambda-expression* appearing in a default argument shall not implicitly or explicitly capture any entity.
>   [ *Example:*
>
> ```cpp
> void f2() {
>     int i = 1;
>     void g1(int = ([i]{ return i; })()); // ill-formed
>     void g2(int = ([i]{ return 0; })()); // ill-formed
>     void g3(int = ([=]{ return i; })()); // ill-formed
>     void g4(int = ([=]{ return 0; })()); // OK
>     void g5(int = ([]{ return sizeof i; })()); // OK
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

However, can we also use a lambda-expression itself as the default value for a function argument?

e.g.

```cpp
template<typename functor>
void foo(functor const& f = [](int x){ return x; })
{
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes. In this respect lambda expressions are no different from other expressions (like, say, `0`). But note that deduction is not used with defaulted parameters. In other words, if you declare

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T = 0);
```

then `foo(0);` will call `foo<int>` but `foo()` is ill-formed. You'd need to call `foo<int>()` explicitly. Since in your case you're using a lambda expression nobody can call `foo` since the type of the expression (at the site of the default parameter) is unique. However you can do:

```
// perhaps hide in a detail namespace or some such
auto default_parameter = [](int x) { return x; };

template<
    typename Functor = decltype(default_parameter)
>
void foo(Functor f = default_parameter);
```

Comment: Hi, +1, thanks for that answer, helped me a lot. I have a few questions though: is it because the template argument deduction is not used for default parameters that the `default_parameter` needs to be explicitly defined? If yes, why isn't the template argument deduced from the default argument, because of (possible) implicit type conversion in the general case? Is there any good link that covers this (that's not the standard)?

Comment: @tmaric That’s right, default arguments are part of a so-called non-deduced context. I don’t know of any rationale as to why the Standard defines it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I'll just then remember that I have to use it in this way. :)

Comment: @LucDanton: Please, can you demonstrate the same without using templates?

Comment: @sergiol You can write `void foo(decltype(default_parameter) f = default_parameter);` but then you can’t call `foo` with anything else than `default_parameter` (or a copy of it), which seems to make the whole thing pointless. You can use an `std::function<Sig>` of the appropriate `Sig` (e.g. `int(int)` in our example), but you’d need a good reason to do it as it’s a *very* roundabout way of doing the same thing as writing a function template to begin with. (A function pointer parameter may also be an option but I also suggest against it, it’s less flexible.)

Comment: @LucDanton: I was searching solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100432/how-can-i-initialize-the-default-value-of-a-carraycclass-function-parameter-w where in the **Approach 3** I tried a lambda, but it was not successful :(

Comment: @LucDanton The last edit is from 2015. Are there new shorter possibilities with C++17?