# How can I initialize the default value of a CArray<CClass*> function parameter with an empty CArray?

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, default-value, assignment-operator

I know I could do this better with `std::vector`, but the application I am messing with, has already a bunch of `CArray` parameters on a lot of related functions ... and I will not change them all at the moment!

I simply want to define an empty `CArray<CClass*>` — array of **pointers** to `CClass`, so the problem **can not be** on the `CClass` constructor — as the default value of a function parameter.

**Approach 1**

If I try to do it with *assignment operator* and *default constructor*:

```
void Function(CArray<CClass*> parameter = CArray<CClass*>());
```

I get the error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxTempl.h(262): error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(535) : see declaration of 'CObject::CObject'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(510) : see declaration of 'CObject'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CArray<TYPE>::CArray(const CArray<TYPE> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=CClass *
1>          ]
```

**Approach 2**

I also tried with a *copy constructor*:

```
void Function(CArray<Class*> parameter(CArray<CClass*>()));
```

I got the errors:

```
 >File.cpp(line X): error C2664: 'FunctionClass::Function' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CArray<TYPE>' to 'CArray<TYPE> (__cdecl *)(CArray<TYPE> (__cdecl *)(void))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=CClass*
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

- line X: contains a call supplying the parameter to Function, as shown: `pFunctionClass->Function(parameter);`

1>CFunctionClass.cpp(line Y): error C2511: 'void CFunctionClass::Function(CArray)' : overloaded member function not found in 'CShoePlaceDoc'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=CClass*
1>          ]
1>          FunctionClass.h(line A) : see declaration of 'CFunctionClass'

- line Y contains the `Function` implementation header, as shown: `void CFunctionClass::Function(CArray parameter)

1>File.cpp(line Z): error C2660: 'CClassFunction::Function' : function does not take 0 arguments

- line Z: contains a call to `Function`without supplying it parameters, as shown: `pClassFunction->Function();`

The approach didn't work, but it got its way towards a **conclusion**: It is not possible to use a copy-constructor for assigning a default value for a function parameter.

**Approach 3**

And if I try with a *lambda*:

```
void Function(CArray<CClass*> parameter = [] () -> CArray<CClass*>{ return CArray<CClass*> (); } );
```

, then I will get multiple outputs of these two errors:

```
1>FunctionClass.h(line A): error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda2>' to 'CArray<TYPE>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=CClass*
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>FunctionClass.h(line B): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

- line A: method declaration
- line B: closing `}` of `FunctionClass` class that contains `Function` method

**Origin of the problem**

The root cause of the problem seems to be the fact that `CArray` is a class directly derived from `CObject`, which declares the assignment operator as private:

```
class AFX_NOVTABLE CObject
{
//...
private:
    CObject(const CObject& objectSrc);              // no implementation
    void operator=(const CObject& objectSrc);       // no implementation
//...
}
```

So, how can I supply an empty array as default value for the parameter?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. Even if you could solve the problem with copy constructor and assignment operator, why would you want it? It's better to access pointers directly. Something like this: `void Function(CArray<CClass*> *p = NULL){if (p == NULL){p = Default;}...}`

Answer (score 0):

With this declaration

```
void Function(CArray<CClass*> parameter /*...*/);
```

You can't. Calling this function will invoke the private copy constructor of `CObject` as you have noticed.

What you could do, is to add a object of `static CArray<CClass*>` in your class and initialize the function with a reference to it. This way it will be empty *(as long as you do not populate it...)* and you can perform a [`.IsEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcachs95.aspx) check on it.

```
private:
    static CArray<CClass*> myObj;
//...
void Function(CArray<CClass*> &parameter = myObj);
```

Or initialize it to 0. This way you simply check it by `if (parameter)` or `if (NULL == parameter)`.

```
void Function(CArray<CClass*> *parameter = NULL);
```